# What is the right way to import library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm getting an error when I import `sklearn`. I have tried both

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

and

```
import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn
```

but neither works. Here is the syntax error I'm seeing:

```
import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn
imputer= Imputer(missing_values='np.nan',strategy='mean',axis=0)
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3]=imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
  File "<ipython-input-47-f72dbfc2a636>", line 1
    import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `from sklearn import impute.SimpleImputer` or `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan: `from sklearn import impute.SimpleImputer` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

and use it like:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer()
```

What does this syntax mean:

```
from sklearn.impute ...
```

From the package named `sklearn` which has a module named `impute`

```
import SimpleImputer
```

import the class/variable/function `SimpleImputer`